# Flushing from a RecordControl w/o calling commit()

Tags: java-me

I'm developing on the Samsung Instinct, so I'm not certain that this question is relevant across other J2ME platforms.  On the Instinct, when I start recording with a RecordControl, the receiving output stream remains empty until I call commit().  Is there a way to purge the so-far recorded data from a RecordControl to the output stream without calling commit()?

Answer (score 1):

Call reset()

http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/control/RecordControl.html#reset()